# Client [/rviz_15....] wants topic /odom to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/PointCloud/d8....], but our version has [nav_msgs/Odometry/cd

Tags: navigation, odometry, rviz, sensor-msgs, nav-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I’m getting this error:
The robot launch file starts and all appears good.
I start rviz then I get one Pose array dataset then this error

```
[ERROR] [1556066738.031123079]: Client [/rviz_1556066697211260013] wants topic /odom to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/PointCloud/d8e9c3f5afbdd8a130fd1d2763945fca], but our version has [nav_msgs/Odometry/cd5e73d190d741a2f92e81eda573aca7]. Dropping connection.
```

This message seems to indicate the required data type should be [sensor_msgs/PointCloud] However, all the ROS info seems to indicate the proper /odom data type is [nav_msgs/Odometry]
At this time I suspect a AMCL or a RVIZ setup issue

Here is the AMCL launch file

```
<launch>
<node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen">
  <!-- Publish scans from best pose at a max of 10 Hz -->
  <param name="odom_model_type" value="diff"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha5" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="initial_pose_x" value="-3.8"/>
  <param name="initial_pose_y" value="6.0"/>
  <param name="initial_pose_a" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="gui_publish_rate" value="1.0"/>
  <param name="laser_max_beams" value="30"/>
  <param name="min_particles" value="500"/>
  <param name="max_particles" value="5000"/>
  <param name="kld_err" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="kld_z" value="0.99"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha1" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha2" value="0.2"/>
  <!-- translation std dev, m -->
  <param name="odom_alpha3" value="0.8"/>
  <param name="odom_alpha4" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="laser_z_hit" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="laser_z_short" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="laser_z_max" value="0.05"/>
  <param name="laser_z_rand" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="laser_sigma_hit" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="laser_lambda_short" value="0.1"/>
  <param name="laser_model_type" value="likelihood_field"/>
  <!-- <param name="laser_model_type" value="beam"/> -->
  <param name="laser_likelihood_max_dist" value="2.0"/>
  <param name="update_min_d" value="0.2"/>
  <param name="update_min_a" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="odom_frame_id" value="odom"/>
  <param name="resample_interval" value="1"/>
  <param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.5"/>
  <param name="recovery_alpha_slow" value="0.0"/>
  <param name="recovery_alpha_fast" value="0.0"/>
</node>
</launch>
```

4/25/2019 - Thank you gvdhoorn for boosting my karma - I will keep my images limited to GUI's - Charlie

[image: image description]
[image: image description]
[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321736/client-%5B/rviz_15....%5D-wants-topic-/odom-to-have-datatype/md5sum-%5Bsensor_msgs/pointcloud/d8....%5D,-but-our-version-has-%5Bnav_msgs/odometry/cd...-dropping-connection./) by [CharlieD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4148/charlied/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-04-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2019-04-24**:
You are correct, this is almost certainly an issue with your rviz config. Can you post your rviz config file or a screenshot of rviz?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-04-25**:
I second @ahendrix. As you haven't posted the config yet: I don't think this has anything to do with the `particlecloud`. Check your configured display types, identify the one that is used to display a pointcloud and check if the topic configured there is called `odom`. If yes, remove and you should be good to go.

More hints to debug: `rostopic info /odom` should show you who is trying to publish/subscribe, `rosnode info <NODE>` should give you more info about the types the respective nodes expect.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-25**:\

> evidently I cannot post images

@CharlieD: I've given you sufficient karma to post a screenshot.

Know that this (ie: as a GUI is involved) is just about the only situation in which posting a screenshot makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your screenshot shows that you have a `PointCloud` display (the last one) where you have the `Topic` field set to `odom`. That is most likely the cause of your problems: the `odom` topic rarely carries `sensor_msgs/PointCloud2` messages, so that is not going to work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CharlieD](https://answers.ros.org/users/4148/charlied/) on 2019-04-25**:
This was the issue, I deleted the PointCloud display and the error disappeared. I was able to manually drive the robot around and the PoseArray updated as expected. Thank You